# Add property to existing field type

Tags: 8, entities

I have troubles adding a simple additional properties (like *alt* or *title*) to the image field type.

In the .module file I defined an alternative class for the image field.

```
function image_video_link_field_info_alter(&$info) {
  // Change the default widget for fields of type 'image'.
  if (isset($info['image'])) {
    $info['image']['class'] = '\Drupal\image_video_link\LinkedImageItem';
    #$info['image']['column_groups']['videolink'] = ['label' => t('Link to a video.')];
  }
}
```

I extended the `ImageItem` class with some additional properties.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\image_video_link\LinkedImageItem.
 */

namespace Drupal\image_video_link;

use Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;

/**
 * Extends the default PathItem implementation to generate aliases.
 */
class LinkedImageItem extends ImageItem {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function defaultStorageSettings() {
    $settings = parent::defaultStorageSettings();
    $settings['default_image']['videolink'] = '';
    return $settings;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function defaultFieldSettings() {
    $settings = parent::defaultFieldSettings();
    $settings['default_image']['videolink'] = '';
    return $settings;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $schema = parent::schema($field_definition);
    $schema['columns']['videolink'] = [
      'description' => "Link to a video.",
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 512,
    ];
    return $schema;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties = parent::propertyDefinitions($field_definition);

    $properties['videolink'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Videolink'))
      ->setDescription(t("Link to a video on Vimeo."));

    return $properties;
  }
}
```

I believe I have to update the database in the .install file as I am getting the following error.

> Undefined property: stdClass::$field_gallery_videolink

How do I do that? Is my method even valid?

Comment: Have a look at [File Entity (fieldable files)](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity). It allows you to add 'custom fields' for files / media - including images.

Comment: I already considered it, but this would require too much testing and would be simply an overkill, as I only need to extend the existing fieldtype.

Comment: Yes, you need to implement hook_update_N(). See this issue for reference https://www.drupal.org/node/2542748

Comment: Would you care to give me a code example? I already have existing entities. Do I need to save them in an object and migrate them once the new field storage is set up?

Comment: Sorry, writing an example of the needed code is almost solving the job. You want to write a hook_update_N() to just add a new column (with a default value) to the table of all fields of the given type. So you need to get the list of fields, and perform `$schema->addField('mytable1', 'newcol', $spec);` See this change record (reachable from the previous link) https://www.drupal.org/node/2554097 and also this page on how to add columns to a table: https://www.drupal.org/node/2535384

Comment: I have already done so before, but the error still remains (see the last line)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a older issue but I found it when trying to do the same. Still for this exactly case maybe answer from xxx would be also helpful.

After it took me a while to figure out how to do it I wanted to share this example. Only thing needs to change is the first few lines.

```
/**
 * Add new property to all fields of type XXX.
 */
function XXX_update_80YY() {
  $field_type = 'XXX';
  $new_properties = array(
    'PROPERTY_NAME' => array(
      'description' => 'PROPERTY DESCRIPTION',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
    ),
  );

  $definition_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManagerInterface $field_manager */
  $field_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager $entity_type_manager */
  $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
  $field_map = $field_manager->getFieldMapByFieldType($field_type);
  $schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
  foreach ($field_map as $entity_type_id => $fields) {
    $field_manager->clearCachedFieldDefinitions();
    $storage_definitions = $field_manager->getFieldStorageDefinitions($entity_type_id);

    $storage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage($entity_type_id);
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\DefaultTableMapping $table_mapping */
    $table_mapping = $storage->getTableMapping();

    foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field) {
      $storage_definition = $storage_definitions[$field_name];
      if (!empty($storage_definition)) {
        $column_names = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($field_name);
        $table_names = [ $table_mapping->getFieldTableName($field_name) ];

        if ($storage_definition->isRevisionable()) {
          $table_names[] = $table_mapping->getDedicatedRevisionTableName($storage_definition);
        }

        foreach ($table_names as $table_name) {
          foreach ($new_properties as $property_name => $property_spec) {
            if (!$schema->fieldExists($table_name, $column_names[$property_name])) {
              $schema->addField($table_name, $column_names[$property_name], $property_spec);
            }
          }
        }
        $definition_update_manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($storage_definition);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for a field type that had one field created against a Commerce profile. I went with the helper function in https://gist.github.com/JPustkuchen/ce53d40303a51ca5f17ce7f48c363b9b

Comment: The last line here, re-established the old field definition...

Comment: Hi, an error here:               ``$schema->addField($table_name, $column_names[$property_name], $property_spec);``

Should be:

``$schema->addField($table_name, $property_name, $property_spec);`` ,  $column_names[$property_name] is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you should use hook_field_attach_update [Hook Filed Attach Update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_attach_update().
*/
function mymodule_field_attach_update($entity_type, $entity) {
 // The other way around: you upload a new image on a node and enter    alt/title tags.
// Save alt and title text from the image field to the file entity,
// but ONLY if the file entity's alt/title fields are empty.
if ($entity_type == 'node') {  
 list(, , $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);
// Examine every image field instance attached to this entity's bundle.
 $instances = array_intersect_key(field_info_instances($entity_type,$bundle), _file_entity_get_fields_by_type('image'));
foreach ($instances as $field_name => $instance) {
  if (!empty($entity->{$field_name})) {
    foreach ($entity->{$field_name} as $langcode => $items) {
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $file = file_load($item['fid']);
        if ($file) {
          if (isset($file->field_file_image_alt_text) && empty($file->field_file_image_alt_text[$langcode][0]['value'])) { 
            $file->field_file_image_alt_text[$langcode][0]['value'] = $item['alt'];
          }
          if (isset($file->field_file_image_title_text) && empty($file->field_file_image_title_text[$langcode][0]['value'])) { 
            $file->field_file_image_title_text[$langcode][0]['value'] = $item['title'];
          }
        }
        field_attach_update('file', $file);
      }
    }
  }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This does not relate to drupal 8...

Comment: please check this link http://api.hostdog.eu/api/drupal-8/drupal!core!modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_update/8.x

Comment: field api for 8  http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!core!modules!field!field.module/group/field/8

Comment: You should check the actual codebase. This hook does not exist anymore

Comment: I know there is a field API but I would like an answer to my question, that's why I opened the thread. I need someone to give me a hint what to do with the error and how to add the db column if it is even needed

Comment: i understand your problem please check this http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!core!modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_info/8         may be this helps you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29152/discussion-between-kamal-oberoi-and-alexej-d).